# NSObject does not have a member named startIndex

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6.3

```
@IBAction func logEmButn(sender: AnyObject) {
    let clonCountrLableItem = clonCountLable.text!
    let baclCounterLableItem = baclCountLable.text!
    let ironCountLableItem = ironCountLable.text!
    let gymCountLableItem = gymCountLable.text!
    let asp2CountLableItem = asp2CountLable.text!
    let fiveHtpLableItem = fiveHtpLable.text!


    let selectedLables = [clonCountLable, baclCountLable, ironCountLable, gymCountLable, asp2CountLable, fiveHtpLable]

    for selectedLable in selectedLables {
        if selectedLable != "0 s" {

            println("You took \(selectedLable[selectedLable.startIndex])")
```

was working earlier today in a "similar" project, now it gives error

> 'NSObject' does not have a member named 'startIndex'

so, I tried:

```
println("You took \(selectedLable[selectedLable.description]) \(keyOfselectedLables)")
```

which gives a similar error, but ends with ... named 'subscript'

also have tried:

```
            let lable = "rick"
            for index in indices(lable) {
                print("\(lable[index])")

            }
```

which give error at runtime of : Could not cast value of type 'UILable' (0x199943e30) to 'NSString' (0x198fb2768).

Comment: You haven't really provided enough information here. Please start by showing how `selectedLable` is declared.

Comment: PSA: Label is spelled "label".

Answer (score 1):

See the below code, selectedLables is an array of UILabel's

```
let selectedLables = [clonCountLable, baclCountLable, ironCountLable, gymCountLable, asp2CountLable, fiveHtpLable]
```

but in the if statement you are equating selectedLable, of type UILabel, with a string constant.

```
for selectedLable in selectedLables {
    if selectedLable != "0 s"
```

Since selectedLable is not a string type, it does not have a startIndex property or index.

So i think the array should be

```
let selectedLables = [baclCounterLableItem, ironCountLableItem, gymCountLableItem, asp2CountLableItem, fiveHtpLableItem]
```

Comment: Nitheesh George: you saved the day, all is now working, thank you so much!!

Comment: If your issue solved completely then please mark it as the answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Nitheesh George nailed it. (the last answer I see here.) Sorry if I messed up the flow here, total nube.